# Using angularJS smart table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

I would like to use AngularJS smart table for my site. I have gone through the documentation([smart table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#section-basics)). Having hard time to understand how does the app.factory works here. I want to know how to implement createRandomItem function for the data I have in the database(mongodb).

```
app.factory('Resource', ['$q', '$filter', '$timeout', function ($q, $filter, $timeout) {

    //this would be the service to call your server, a standard bridge between your model an $http

    // the database (normally on your server)
    var randomsItems = [];

    function createRandomItem(id) {
        var heroes = ['Batman', 'Superman', 'Robin', 'Thor', 'Hulk', 'Niki Larson', 'Stark', 'Bob Leponge'];
        return {
            id: id,
            name: heroes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)],
            age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
            saved: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
        };

    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        randomsItems.push(createRandomItem(i));
    }


    //fake call to the server, normally this service would serialize table state to send it to the server (with query parameters for example) and parse the response
    //in our case, it actually performs the logic which would happened in the server
    function getPage(start, number, params) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var filtered = params.search.predicateObject ? $filter('filter')(randomsItems, params.search.predicateObject) : randomsItems;
if (params.sort.predicate) {
            filtered = $filter('orderBy')(filtered, params.sort.predicate, params.sort.reverse);
        }

        var result = filtered.slice(start, start + number);

        $timeout(function () {
            //note, the server passes the information about the data set size
            deferred.resolve({
                data: result,
                numberOfPages: Math.ceil(filtered.length / number)
            });
        }, 1500);


        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
        getPage: getPage
    };

}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok... My Time to Shine.. :D.... Just kidding.. you answer is bellow..

Well this a fairly straight forward example, if you are familiar with angular factory.

when you use a factory service it executes the code inside the factory's definition and return whatever you would just like calling a function.

So what the above code is doing is when you use this factory service simply generates a list of random items(Avengers) into the array `randomItems` that step is fairly simple. if you look at the `createRandomItem(id)` and the `for` loop after it.

the trick however is in `getPage()` and what the `Resource factory` is returning. So lets go on a journey.

in the code where `Resource` factory is used when you call `Resourse.getPage()` it'll return a `promise` object on which you can call other JS functions. and inside `getPage()` as you can see it has set a `timeout` to call `resolve`  with an object that has variables `data` and `numberOfPages` in it, on the `deffered` object which triggers `doneCallback` on the `promise` of that `deffered` object.

so when you service like

```
Resourse.getPage(1,2,3) // please see the use of these arguments inside the  getPage function
.done(function(result){
   result.data; //the fake server data from the factory
   result.numberOfPages; //this is computed in factory as well
});
```

When 1500ms pass the function/callback passed to done gets trigerred.

## Summary and Answer

**Note: Please read above first it took me hell of a time to write that.**

Now to address your problem. what you can do is modify this

```
app.factory('Resource', ['$q', '$filter', '$timeout', function ($q, $filter, $timeout)
```

to

```
app.factory('Resource', ['$http', '$q', '$filter', '$timeout', function ($http, $q, $filter, $timeout)
```

an use `$http` to retrieve `data` from the server or `mongodb` and fill in an array with your data from server.

```
$http.get(server_url).success(function(response){
    //....do something with the response from the server like filtering etc.. 
    //finally..
    deferred.resolve({
       data: response
    });
});
```

an finally when using service

```
Resourse.getPage(1,2,3) //what ever you want to pass its not necessory to pass the same as above
  .done(function(response){
     //do what ever you want to do with response from your factory.. PHEW...
   });
```

P.S.0. its the longest answer I've provided to date.. PHEW :P

P.S.1. Please feel free to ask any question in the comments

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I got it. :)